# i have a stamp which has a check mark and current date. i need to add this stamp to all the pages in a pdf using itext and java

Tags: java, itext, pdfstamper

I have a stamp which has a check mark and current date on it.
I need to add this stamp to all the pages in a pdf on click of a button using itext and java.
The stamp is a form having a text field where in the date is entered automatically using javascript.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfReader s_reader = new PdfReader(stationery);
// Create the stamper
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
// Add the stationery to each page
PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(s_reader, 1);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfContentByte background;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    background = stamper.getUnderContent(i);
    background.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
}
// Close the stamper
stamper.close();
reader.close();
s_reader.close();
```

Now, how to get that saved stamp (form) from the pdf, add current date to it and how do I add this stamp to all the pages of a Pdf document?
Is the javascript needed?

Comment: make a header in your pdf and do your stuff on header see `PdfPageEventHelper`

Comment: thanks for your reply. but, i have the stamp preformatted in a pdf file. it has borders around it, and a check mark and the current date. as of now, i am manually adding the stamp. i get the date from javascript automatically. but, on each page i need to add the stamp.\

Comment: what kind of stamp is this . it is a text or some image

Comment: it is not an image, it has some text, borders and in the middle, has a date field. like controlled copy, bangalore, etc

Comment: you already have pdf and you want to add stamp on it, you are not creating it while adding stamp

Comment: yes. thats the requirement. i need to add pdf stamp on all pages of a document

Comment: wont it be time consuming if a create it to add to each page? how do i create the stamp with text, and current date and put it on lower bottom left corner on each page?

Comment: i did the same thing what you want but i'm creating the pdf not reading it. So in your case hv to do some R&D

Comment: oh ok. creating...... wont it be time consuming ? say if trhe document has 100 pages..... and then i do it for 10 such documents...... creating. how did you add the date to stamp and tehn the stamp to pdf?

Comment: no issue in creating .i'm creating pdf of almost 1000 pages even more it took some time but work just fine

Comment: The task would be clearer if you shared sample PDFs.

Comment: how do i attach files here? i M NOT ABLE TO FIND ANY HELP re THIS

Comment: stackoverflow does only allow attaching images. In case of other data, you have to share them publicly elsewhere, e.g. from a googledrive or dropbox account. Please do not use a service that requires registration of the downloader or forces many ads upon you.

Comment: oh ok i shall attach it using googledrive

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7CypzNT0ebzM0RMSU9VYmRqOXJ2SjVad0dpUlpCVVRiaXVZ/view?usp=sharing is the document which has to be stamped

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7CypzNT0ebzNWFlVzZUSUZDMHI4Y0ctbGJMNVpBUGI5b0xn/view?usp=sharing is the document with my stamp

Comment: the stamp is on the 2nd page. in the middle the date should come automatically. currently have done it using javascript. so when i select the stamp the date comes. but, now i have to automate it. on click of a button, all the pages of the pdf have to be stamped

Comment: As I see you found a workaround by drawing something similar to the stamp you are given on every page using a `PdfStamper`. If the stamp won't change (at least not often), that is the easiest way to  implement this.

Comment: yup, thanks much for all the support :)

Answer (score 1):

**To create pdf**

```
private static final Font headerFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9,
            Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 120, 50);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(realPath + "/PdfTable.pdf"));
        writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788));
        HeaderFooterOfPdf event = new HeaderFooterOfPdf(batchDate);
        writer.setPageEvent(event);
        document.open();
//to create table
PdfPTable vppTable = new PdfPTable(new float[]{3, 7, 9, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4});
        vppTable.setWidthPercentage(100f);
//pdf table header
        vppTable.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Your column name", headerFont)));
        vppTable.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Your column name", headerFont)));
        vppTable.setHeaderRows(1);

//to add cell data
PdfPCell slNoCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("your data", contentFont));
            slNoCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            slNoCell.setPaddingLeft(15f);
            vppTable.addCell(slNoCell);

document.add(vppTable);
document.close();
```

**HeaderFooterOfPdf class**

```
public class HeaderFooterOfPdf extends PdfPageEventHelper{

public HeaderFooterOfPdf(String batchDate){
        this.batchDate = batchDate;
    }

@Override
    public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    }

@Override
    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
//do what you want to enter on header
}

@Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
//do what you want to enter on footer
}
}
```

Comment: batch date is simple date in `String` form and headerfont is the font for your header check i update the answer

Comment: ITS GIVING ME ERROR on line this.batchDate = batchDate; saying cannot find symbol variable batchDate

Comment: you have to create a varibale of String type in HeaderFooterOfPdf class like `private String batchDate;`. Are you new to java.

Comment: hi, i have uploaded the files on google drive. please view them for more clarity

Comment: you uploaded on your drive but you didn't share it with me so i can't see that

Comment: hi i have made it public, if u just click on the link, it opens up

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.*;  
import java.util.Set;  
import java.util.TreeSet;

import java.text.*;

//itext libraries to read & write to a PDF file
import com.itextpdf.text.*;  
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;  
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;  
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;  
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;  
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;  
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;  
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;  
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;  
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;  
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;  
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;  
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;  
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;  
import com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily;  
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;    
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;    
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;    
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;  


public class TwoPasses1  
{  
   public static final String RESULT = "K:\\DCIN_TER\\DCIN_EPU2\\CIRCUIT FROM BRANCH\\RAINBOW ORDERS\\111111\\PADR Release\\Final PADR Release 1.pdf";

         public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException
        {
         // ADD THE FOOTER, Create a reader
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("K:\\DCIN_TER\\DCIN_EPU2\\CIRCUIT FROM BRANCH\\RAINBOW ORDERS\\111111\\PADR Release\\Final PADR Release.pdf");

         // Create a stamper
         PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));

         // Loop over the pages and add a footer to each page
         int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

         for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                {
                         getFooterTable(i, n).writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 80, stamper.getOverContent(i));

                        // getFooterTable(i, n).writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, stamper.getOverContent(i));
         }

         // Close the stamper
         stamper.close();

         reader.close();
         }

        public static PdfPTable getFooterTable(int x, int y)
        {
         java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

                String month = sdf.format(date);
                System.out.println("Month : " + month);

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

         table.setTotalWidth(150);
         table.setLockedWidth(true);

         table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorTop(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorRight(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthTop(2f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthLeft(2f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthRight(2f);

         table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

                Font font1 = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE);

         table.addCell(new Phrase("CONTROLLED COPY", font1));

         table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorRight(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthLeft(2f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthRight(2f);

         table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

                Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED);

         table.addCell(new Phrase(month, font));

         table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorRight(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorBottom(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthLeft(2f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthRight(2f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthBottom(2f);

         table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

         table.addCell(new Phrase("BLR DESIGN DEPT.", font1));

         return table;
         }
}
```

Comment: thanks amit. i tried what you had suggested yesterday regarding header. keeping this as the base, i worked. my code may be very silly. but, it serves my purpose